# editor grid head and body move separately

Tags: extjs, extjs2

I am using Editor grid which have 15 columns due to which horizontal scroll bar exist. In normal mode it works fine, but if I select any of editable grid items and move horizontal scroll bar to extreme right grid header and body moves independently. Any suggestion to fix this problem? After selecting any cell scrollbar shrinks and total width of column values reducing and header width not resizing with respect to the column values width.

Comment: added css fix for this issue .x-grid3-focus{left: 0 !important;}